Announcing an upcoming election
Summary: Psychology & Neuroscience Stack Exchange will begin the nomination stage for an election on September 20, as your "graduation" election (as a result of having lost your beta label a while back).
The timeline:

On September 13, I'll post a question collection post on Meta, so that the community can post questions they'd like to see the candidates answer.

Starting on September 20, users can nominate themselves. The top questions collected on the previous week will be compiled into a second Meta post, so that potential moderators can answer them.

On September 27, if there are five or more candidates, we'll run an election. If not, we'll extend the nomination period for one more week. If at the end of this extension period there are still not five or more candidates, I'll simply cancel the election and check with the moderation team on who's sticking around and how many extra hands might be needed, and appoint the appropriate number of candidates as pro-tem mods (for full details of the process, see the announcement on Meta Stack Exchange). (There's a small chance we'll need to remove a nomination, but I doubt that will come up.)

If there is an election, I'll announce the results on meta on October 5 (or on the 12th, if we need to extend the nomination period and only get 5 or more candidates then).


If you have any questions about the process, please stick them in an answer here.
